# Checking an external list for duplicates in MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, excel

I have a MySQL table and an Excel file.  I would like to update the MySQL table to include the information from the Excel file, which is simple -- just write a quick formula for each line that creates the appropriate SQL statement.

But first I'd like to check that all of the data matches properly.  So if a given line has WidgetID 1001, I'd like to check if that WidgetID is in the MySQL table.  For a given line, that's simple -- just generate a SQL statement

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE WidgetID = "1001"
```

and execute it.  But how can I check all lines without pasting in the commands one at a time?  Essentially, I want something like

```
If (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE WidgetID = "1001") = 0 Display "1001\n"
```

but I'm not sure how to do this.  (I don't use SQL much!)

**Clarification:** I do *not* want to import the data at this time!  That will be a complicated task because the data need to be transformed and entered into a dozen different tables in various ways.  Right now I just want to check for non-duplicates (which will be almost entirely errors, I imagine, though some perhaps will be actual new entries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Export Excel to CSV
2. Make sure there is a UNIQUE index created on `WidgetID` column
3. Use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) with REPLACE or IGNORE option (depending if you want to replace duplicates with new values, or leave the previous values)

Comment: All of the entries should be duplicates.  Right now I don't want to import the data because some of the entries will not be duplicates -- they'll have typos or other mistakes that cause them to not match.  All I want is to find the non-duplicates, *not* to import the data.  (Importing will be much more complicated, since the data will need to go into many different tables.)

Comment: Ok then. I'll tell you what I'd do. I would still use LOAD DATA INFILE to load CSV data into a temporary (not MySQL TEMPORARY - just temporary in the meaning it will be used for temporary storage of data) table and then use a simple query with left join to find not matching entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can query both MySQL and Excel at the same time, this is an INSERT, but any query will work:

[Excel VBA: writing to mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821718/excel-vba-writing-to-mysql-database/2821911#2821911)

Here is another example with SQL Server:

[INSERT data from Excel into SQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767879/insert-data-from-excel-into-sql-db/3768327#3768327)

You can get both OLE DB & ODBC connection strings from: http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=81